# How to add attachment in invoice?

Tags: magento2, email, invoice, sales-invoice

I have overrided **`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender`** and tried the below code to add the attachment

```
$filename = 'e:\tushar\smtp_gmail.pdf';
$this->attachFile(file_get_contents($filename),'test.pdf');

public function attachFile($file, $name) {
        if (!empty($file) && file_exists($file)) {
            $this->message
            ->createAttachment(
                file_get_contents($file),
                \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                basename($name)
                );
            }

        return $this;
    }
```

but it's not working

Comment: e:\ part of e:\tushar\smtp_gmail.pdf suggest pdf is on your computer.

You would need to upload to webserver and then perform similar action but using file path of pdf attachment on server.

Comment: @DominicXigen the file is already on server and i just want to attach that file as an attachment in invoice email..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an extension?

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-email-attachments

Best of all - this extension is free

> Magnento 2 Email Attachments by Mageplaza allows attaching important billing documents as PDF invoice, Credit Memo, Shipment and adds Terms and Conditions to sales emails. This helps customers follow all purchasing information while checking emails from stores.